# Compare Table with a monitoring point - mysql

Tags: mysql, compare

i have a table that contains product data with prices. The table updated every 5 - 10 minutes.
Now i have a cronjob that makes a monitoring point by copying the table.
So i get a copy of the data every morning.

Now i want to check my prices at the evening by comparing them with the monitor table.

How could my query look like to get the two prices.
The query should show products where the prices are different.

```
Table a
[id] - [product_no] [product_desc] [product_price] - [product_stock]

Table b (from cronjob]
[id] - [product_no] [product_desc] [product_price] - [product_stock]
```

Comment: This is not a very efficient solution. A better solution would be to use a single table with some sort of version indicator (optionally a view for accessing the consolidated table as if it were the original one) and perhaps deleting historic data - or even shunting the data across columns when it changes.

Comment: can you be a little more specific? i dont know how to use views in mysql. do you mean that i should create a column for the values for monitoring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask for a basic join between two tables. Here is how a join can be performed:

```
SELECT TableA.product_no
     , TableA.product_price AS TableAPrice
     , TableB.product_price AS TableBPrice
FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB
        ON TableA.id = TableB.id
WHERE TableA.product_price != TableB.product_price
```

Try to learn how joins are working in general, this is a very important thing to know when working with databases.